# Codemagic: Ios build - No valid code signing certificates were found

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I don't have a Mac nor an Iphone, I'm trying to build and sign and distribute the flutter app to IOS app store via codemagic.

I already have an API key and enabled auto signing via the web interface, I keep getting this error though, any idea how to fix it without Xcode?

I have access to Apple developer account. I'm using release mode, "Building IOS" step failed. I'm on windows but I have access to Debian via wsl on windows and I have access to OpenSSL on Linux as well.

```
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment


Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

Comment: do you have an access to Developer Apple? which step was failed? which mode you use to build ios (debug, profile, release)?

Answer (score 1):

To someone struggling with this, just ctrl+shift+F PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and change it with your app bundle identifier from App Store Connect.

// OLD

PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.testApp

// NEW

PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.myapp.bundlename

just do this for every PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER value.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely you don't have a certificate created in Apple Developer Center. Assuming you're using an API key, to build in debug or profile mode you need to use Apple development certificate (go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Certificates -> + -> Apple Development) and production certificate to build in release mode (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Certificates -> + -> Apple Distribution). <s>But anyway you won't be able to create them without the Mac device, because the certificates creation requires the "Certificate Signing Request" file to be uploaded at some step. This file can only be created via Keychain tool on Macbook or iMac</s>

UPD:

The certificates creation requires the "Certificate Signing Request" file to be uploaded.

Guides for windows:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iLtDb2ZKAE
- https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781849691383/1/ch01lvl1sec11/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-using-windows

Linux:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ios_enterprise.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest
```

Comment: I'm using I have access to Apple developer account. I'm using release mode, "Building IOS" step failed.

Comment: I was told by someone from codemagic that I don't need a mac ever in the process. Are you sure that a mac is absolutely needed to publish on IOS? If so I would need to contact them and ask them about it.

Comment: @Lynob which OS do you use for the development?

Comment: I was mistaken when told that you couldn't create Certificate Signing Request without mac

Comment: I'm on windows but I have access to Debian via wsl on windows and I have access to OpenSSL on Linux as well.

Comment: I created `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` and uploaded it to the App store (the linux command) and re-ran the build and it failed. Should I upload any key file to codemagic?

Comment: Did you create the certificate? (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Certificates -> + -> Apple Distribution). One more question: you're trying to release in TestFligt (or AppStoreConnect)? or trying to make the build available for downloading via CodeMagic

Comment: I hope you went through this guide, right? https://docs.codemagic.io/flutter-code-signing/ios-code-signing/

Comment: I created the certificate and then Apple asked me to upload the certificate I created on windows and I did.  I'm trying to release via AppStoreConnect API key, and it's connected to codemagic. And yes I've read that article but I enabled automatic signing so most of that doesn't apply to me. Should I use manual signing?

Comment: No, you can use only automatic signing. Ok. Lets try to change the xcode version. I think you're using the latest one (14.x), try to downgrade it to 13 or 12 and assemble the build once again

Comment: Hey @Lynob Were you able to publish the App without mac?

Comment: To someone struggling with this, just ctrl+shift+F PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and change it with your app bundle identifier from App Store Connect.

Comment: @PrakharVarshney No, I just bought a Mac Air M1 and I only use it to publish the app